# How to apply graph theory to find shortest path

Tags: math, graph-theory

I'm studying about graph theory. And i meet this problem and don't know how to solve it.

> "The rectangle 2 * 3 squares (1 * 1) inside should have a total of 12
>   vertices and 17 edges. Ask the shortest path through each vertex and
>   each edge at least once will have to go through the total of how many
>   edges."

Please help me find this shortest path.

Answer (score 2):

1) If in your path you come to a vertex you need to go out (if it is not a start or an end of your path)

2) In mean that if you have a vertex with odd number of connected edges you will anyway use one of them twice.

3) In your example you have 6 vertices with odd number of connected edges. One of them could be used as a start and one as a end of the path. So you will have at least 4 vertices with odd connection and at 4 least edges that you should use twice.

4) but one edge connects 2 points so you can use it for 2 vertices with odd connection => 4/2 = 2

5) Consequently the minimum number of edges is 4/2 + 17 = 19. And you can easily find an example for it.

example: 1,0 -> 2,0 -> 2,1 -> 2,2 -> 2,1 -> 1,1 -> 1,0 -> 0,0 -> 0,1 -> 1,1 -> 1,2 -> 2,2 -> 2,3 -> 1,3 -> 1,2 -> 0,2 -> 0,1 -> 0,2 -> 0,3 -> 1,3

Comment: Chepikov: Could you help me to explain detail about "if you have vertex odd number of connected edges you will anyway use one of them twice"?

Comment: @JameLenon If a vertex is not a start or an end point in your path the number of times you enter it equal to the number of times you leave it. It means that number of connected ages you use to enter and leave the vertex is odd number. Consequently if a vertex has even edges connected to it and and each edge used at least once. it means that at least one of them is used twice.